# Returning a character array

Tags: random, character

I wrote a function to generate random names . This is my code

```
 char *getrandumstring(int n)
{
    int i;
    char *str;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {


    str[i] = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
    }

    str[i]='\0';

    return str;
}
```

Now in the line

```
   str[i] = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
```

am getting Segmentation fault. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a segmentation fault because, while you created a pointer, you didn't allocate any backing storage for it.

```
char *getRandomString (int n) {
    int i;
    char *str = malloc (n + 1);
    if (str != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            str[i] = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
        str[n] = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}
```

That code above will allocate the memory successfully and return the buffer. Or, if there's no memory available, it will return NULL. Just remember to free it when you're done.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use dynamic memory allocation, get the caller to provide the buffer as well:

```
void getRandomString (char *str, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str[i] = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
    str[n] = '\0';
}

// Somewhere else in your code:

#define STR_SZ 20
char buffer[STR_SZ+1];
getRandomStr (buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
```

Comment: Thank You. I used second one. But understood first one also.